# weighted interval problem with dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, intervals

I am dealing with a weighted interval problem. In the traditional formulation, we have we have a list {i_1, ..., i_n} of jobs with weights w_j. I found a pretty straightforward approach with example from the book "Algorithm Design" by Kleinberg and Tardos where Dynamic Programming that is based on initially sorting the intervals by finishing time (https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos423/lectures/06dynamic-programming.pdf). The algorithm makes use of the concept p_j (predecessor) which is the largest job i non-conflicting with job j. In my specific case, however, I am dealing with a problem where there are are several jobs with the same finish time, so I would have several p_js. Because of that I am not sure how straightforward or appropriate would be this DP approach for my problem. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that you need to order jobs using `<=` not `<` operator:

[image]

For this formula it doesn't matter if you have several jobs with the same ending time.

[image]

`p(j)` is one with the largest index among jobs with the same finishing time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that p(j) is one with the largest index among jobs with the same finishing time. So that would imply that if I have, let's say 10 jobs with the same finishing time, I would have to calculate OPT(p(j)) for all the 10 jobs? If so, it seems to me that the DP algorithm is losing is "power". Please, let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: @Michele not exactly. `OPT(j-1)` will take care of it, it will make to check all other jobs with the same finishing time anyway. If you use memoization then you don't need to recompute the same `OPT(k)` again, that is the gain.